# Table View and AFNetworking Asynchronous Call

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous, afnetworking-2

I'm new to iOS development and I am trying to figure out what the best solution to my problem would be. I have a `UITableViewController` class which calls a method named `fetchModules` in the `viewDidLoad`. This fetches all the data I need for my table using AFNetworking 2.

However, my table delegate methods such as `numberOfRowsInSection`and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` are failing because the AFNetworking call has not finished yet and the array I am using to store the data has not been populated.

The actual error I am getting is

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException'

Here's my code:

```
#import "HistoryTableViewController.h"

@interface HistoryTableViewController ()

@property NSArray *modules;

@end

@implementation HistoryTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.modules = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    [self fetchModules];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)fetchModules
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:self.token forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];

    [manager GET:@"http://myurl.com/" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        //NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        self.modules = [responseObject objectForKey:@"data"];
    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.modules && self.modules.count) {
        return self.modules.count;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"Cell Identifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    NSDictionary *module = [self.modules objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [module objectForKey:@"code"];

    return cell;
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: same issue with me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much common solution for async network call.

Add `[self.tableView reloadData]` inside the `AFNetworking` success `block`:

```
- (void)fetchModules
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:self.token forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];

    [manager GET:@"http://myurl.com/" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        //NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        self.modules = [responseObject objectForKey:@"data"];

       [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: Hi. Just added that in but still get a NSRangeException. Do I need to stop the table from loading in the first place before the AFNetworking call has been made?

Comment: Working now. Silly me, forgot to change the from static cells to dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I think the conditions should be as below.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.modules != nil && self.modules.count > 0) {
        return self.modules.count;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Also do not forget to reload table after you get the response.

Answer (score 0):

Few corrections may help you. First synthesize property "modules". Also in delegate method for creating Table Cell ensure that if "modules" is empty then that method should do no operation on "modules" property and just return "cell". I hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm new to iOS programming but in one of the tutorials I read, it said I don't need to need synthesize in XCode 5 as it's automatically done for you?